# Upgrading cordova android project v. 2.7 straight to v. 4.1.1

Tags: android, cordova, upgrade

i'm upgrading a cordova v.2.7 android project straight to v. 4.1.1 Is it possible without doing steps described here https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html ?
I'm facing problems with porting a v.2.7 config.xml to a v.4.1.1, especially there are issues with plugins.
In the v.2.7 config.xml there are plugins:

`<plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>`

`<plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />`

Do i need them in the v.4.1.1 config.xml?
Can i simply replace them with these lines?:

`<feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>`

`<feature name="Echo">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.Echo" />
</feature>`

I installed other plugins via `cordova plugin add`, but i can't find plugins "App" and "Echo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was ok without them, so I just removed plugins "App" and "Echo".